# Multiple beam processes with ejabberd

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erlang-shell, erlang-supervisor, beam

I'm working on a chat application built using ejabberd on the backend. Every time I start ejabberd: I see multiple ejabberd/beam process start and after sometime.. I see that one of them is hogging up cpu completely.. Restarting the erlang virtual machine and the whole system fixes this issue for a short while... but reappears again..

Any pointers on how to debug this?

I tried using etop to look at the top processes and processes_info: 
looking at the processes reductions, things looked fine at a high-level.. not sure if I'm missing something?

Any additional tools/things that I'm probably missing? Any pointers would be really appreciated.
I'm using the latest ejabberd and otp/erlang version-22.

Comment: Can you dumps the logs?

Comment: you mean ejabberd logs? they don't show any logs when there's no user activity.. I still see the usage to be about 100 percent..